# What is the probability of the events when we randomly select a permutation of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, soft-question

Question= What is the probability of the events when we randomly select a permutation of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$

a-) $4$ precedes $1$ ,  $4$ precedes $2$ ,  $4$ precedes $3$

b-) $3$ precedes both $7$ and $8$ in the permutation

When i saw these types of questions , i think that i should $\color{red}{ONLY}$ focus on desired numbers. What i meant was i do not tackle the numbers which are not mentioned.

By using my thought

a-) $3!/4!$

b-) $2!/3!$

My question is that whether my approach is true or not. Is only focusing on questioned numbers true ?

Comment: looks good${}{}{}$, and the idea to only focus on relevant numbers also looks good.

Comment: It is not quite clear what is the question a-) about.

Comment: What was the question here? I mean the problem given.

Comment: @user a says that when we permutate the given all of $9$ numbers , what is the probability $4$ precedes $1$ and $4$ precedes $2$ and $4$ precedes $3$

Comment: @user i am asking for the truth of my approach , i mean that is it enough to focus only on wanted numbers

Comment: Comparing this question with b-) I am not sure about "and". Possibly it asks about the probabilities of three different events.

Comment: @user answer key confirm $1/4$.

Comment: @user the point is just my approach. does it need to include the other numbers

Comment: @user if they were different then the answer would be $(1/2)^3=1/8$ ,according to my thought

Comment: @Onir thanks for confirming me

Comment: You point is ok.

Comment: If they were different the answer would be $1/2,1/2,1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good approach would be the following:
Observe that the number of permutations where some digit, say $a$ precedes some other digit, say $b$, would be the SAME as the number of permutations where $b$ precedes $a$. If you are having trouble with this notion, to prove it, all you have to do is observe that a number where $b$ precedes $a$ can be constructed from a number where $a$ precedes $b$ by swapping these two digits. So there is a one to one correspondence, hence the two will have same number of permutations.

Extend this idea to get part (a). Place $1,2$ and $3$ first and see that there are 4 places for the digit $4$ to be. Before $1$, after $3$, between $1$ and $2$ and between $2$ and $3$, all with same number of permutations. We need it to be before $1$. So probability is $\frac 14$. With exactly the same logic you can do part (b) as well.

Comment: it is the same of what i thought

Comment: Alright then, you are correct