# What is the probability of these events when we randomly select a permutation of {1, 2, 3, 4}?

Tags: probability, permutations

The question in my book is: What is the probability of these events when we randomly select a permutation of {1, 2, 3, 4}?

I saw this answer but I didn't understand what was happening.
[What is the probability of the events when we randomly select a permutation of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4135157/what-is-the-probability-of-the-events-when-we-randomly-select-a-permutation-of)

a) 1 precedes 4.

For `a` I've got {1,4,_,_}, {1,_,4,_}, {1,_,_,4}, {_,1,_,4}, {_,_,1,4}. That is 5 ways 1 can precede 4. Those blanks can be 2 or 3 so we need to multiple 5 by 2. That gives us 10 ways 1 can precede 4. The total number of ways is 4! which is 24. That gives us 10/24. The answer in the book is 1/2. What am I doing wrong here?

b) 4 precedes 1.

This is like `a` with the numbers flipped.

c) 4 precedes 1 and 4 precedes 2.

I don't know where to start with this because my `a` is wrong so I've gotten stuck.

Comment: Just by symmetry...it's equally likely that any given number precedes or follows another given number.  Same style of argument can be applied to a choice of three or more.

Comment: Should say:  I can't follow your argument at all.  There are $9!=362880$ permutations on $9$ letters.  I don't understand why you have numbers like $4!$

Comment: Where do you see 9? That was the original question. My question is about {1,2,3,4}

Comment: Oh,  well the symmetry argument still holds.  Clearly you miscounted.  Given any permutation in which $1$ precedes $4$, you can switch the $1,4$ to get a new permutation in which $4$ precedes $1$ so exactly half of them have the desired order.  Given that $4!$ is so small you can simply write out all $24$ permutations to confirm.

Comment: Note:  As a general practice, you should put the question in the body of the text.  It can also appear in the header if you like, but it should always appear in the body.

Comment: Yeah. I understand the symmetry argument but I don't see how it applies in this case. How else can 1 precede 4? Precede means before in this case right? Honestly asking because I'm wondering if that's what I'm getting wrong.

Comment: @lulu `Note: As a general prac....` I added it there now. I'm new to this so still learning.

Comment: Your argument is fine, you're just missing a case: {_, 1, 4, _}

Comment: Note, you could find this mistake yourself pretty easily: Just list off all 24 permutations and check.

Comment: @JairTaylor `Your argument is fine, you're just missing a case: {_, 1, 4, _} `
I just didn't see it. Thanks

Comment: NP. note, I'd also consider learning Python or another language (if you haven't already) so that you can reliably check your work, especially for larger cases where you cannot count them yourself.

Comment: For part (c), the symmetry argument is that given the subset $~\{1,2,4\},~$ any one of these three elements has a (1/3) probability of being selected *before the other two elements in the subset*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you have a random permutation $(1,2,\dots,n)$, then probability that $i$ precedes $j$ is $\frac12$ by symmetry; alrerantively, there are $(n-1)+(n-2)+\dots+2+1$ ways to positon $i$ before $j$ in a permutation, depending on where you position $i$, and $(n-2)!$ ways to position the rest, so the answer is
$$
\frac{[(n-1)+(n-2)+\dots+2+1]\cdot(n-2)!}{n!}
=\frac{\frac{n(n-1)}2\cdot(n-2)!}{n!}=\frac12.
$$
For question (c), to position $i$ before $j$ and $k$, you can use the symmetry again,  but you can also use the counting: $i$ can be positioned at $r=1,2,\dots,n-2$, and $j$ and $k$ have to be placed in $n-r$ cells to the right, there are $(n-r)(n-r-1)$ ways to do it, and the remaining values can be set in $(n-3)!$ ways. So the required probability is
$$
\frac{[(n-1)(n-2)+(n-2)(n-3)+\dots+2\cdot1]\cdot(n-3)!}{n!}
=\frac{\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3}\cdot(n-3)!}{n!}=\frac13.
$$